# Что делать с JSON дальше?

Tags: jquery, json, php, ajax, javascript

Товарищи, вопрос такой - страница php на сервере после ajax-запроса парсит выборку из базы, запихивает ее в JSON и отправляет клиенту. Там ее принимает javaScript, парсит этот JSON в нормальные такие объекты javaScript'а - но они несут тупо информативный характер. Мне же нужно чтобы этим всем объектам привязались необходимые мне контейнеры html. Т.е., допустим, я принимаю с сервера вложенные друг в друга объекты с информацией о годе - корневой объект "год", он контейнер для объектов типа "месяц", и т.д. по цепочке. но как их теперь запихнуть в дивы, вложенные друг в друга, если я передаю их с помощью JSON? Если бы я из php принтил бы вызов конструктора - тогда понятно, а как работать с JSON'ом в данном случае?? Заранее спасибо

Comment: нет, с 99 строкой все в порядке)))это отладочный alert, там вся функциональная нагрузка заключается в том чтобы хайлайтить и измененные объекты, просто тупо для меня и для начальства, чтобы визуально было видно, а alert я делал чтобы увидеть что на update в базу придут верные данные. насчет главного вопроса - в том-то и дело что я не могу использовать json.parse (или указывать в $.ajax "dataType: json", без разницы), потому что в этом случае не вызывается конструктор и не навешивается view (который прописан в конструкторе module, допустим). Если я получаю JSON - это тупо описательный объект.

Comment: пишу здесь потому что в треде почему-то нельзя комменты больше оставлять, наверное из-за низкой кармы.
смотрите, что я получаю на выходе - http://pastebin.com/qPqBn2uh. Это уже javaScript, это УЖЕ объект, его уже не нужно json.parse, все уже готово. что дальше-то делать?)
если я правильно Вас понял, вы имеете ввиду, что надо писать обработчик для уже сформированных объектов JSON. Тут как раз и вопрос который я уже задавал до этого - как примерно это выглядит в данном случае?) хотя бы намекните, куда копать)))

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем вам нужны массивы periods и units. Зачем вы их формируете?  
Без лишних хлопот вам надо всего-то принять json с сервера и построить по нему интерфейс. Повесить обработчики, которые сами знают к каким id они относятся.  
При интерактивных действиях все также принять json, определить (или знать заранее) к какому div'у или div'ам они относятся и внести изменения.  
Кроме того, есть небольшая претензия к json'у. Там везде ассоциативные массивы, которые вы переделываете в итоге в обычные массивы. Неудобство определенное в этом есть...

Comment: Пока я писал эти два файла, я первый раз использовал объекты javaScript, и первый раз использовал jQuery UI, поэтому есть такие вот артефакты). С тем что JSON должен хранить по сути только информацию(такой же декларативный как html) я абсолютно согласен. Вы сформулировали мой вопрос так как я не смог сам) как построить интерфейс по json'у? просто хотя бы небольшой примерчик приведите, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот сделал небольшой [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/7c5EH/2/). Отстраивается принятый json. Плюс пару обработчиков добавил.

Вообще удобнее отстраивать это дело с использованием шаблонизаторов. ejs, swig и проч... Тогда и код сокращается, и скорость выше и редактировать удобнее.

Необходимость в массивах может быть и есть, если логика какая-то специальная заложена, но тогда лучше привязываться к дереву dom, так будет проще, ведь иерархия уже есть и селекторами искать нужные данные довольно легко.

Comment: а что у Вас значит $ перед именами переменных? в этом есть что-то ключевое?) или это просто для удобства? Или это тот самый "глобальный объект jQuery"?

Comment: все, уже понял зачем оно так. не знал что такая веселая штука есть, и в частности, не знал про $some.data(mixed args). спасибо вам большое) немного не то что нужно, но вы указали направление. вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Юра, два вопроса которые у меня возникли после прочтения вашего примера - чем будет отличаться $p=("<div......>") от $p.append("<div......>")? А второй вопрос, уже скорее теоретический - многие говорят на форумах и различных ресурсах, что в javaScript MVC Model и View можно объединять, и даже нужно...но насколько это концептуально верно?

Comment: `$p=$("<div......>")` - это создание элемента, без добавления в dom. адльше его надо добавить будет через $p.appendTo(родитель) или $(родитель).append($p).  
$p.append("<div......>") - добавляет дочерний элемент в конец списка детей.  
В принципе все это не оптимально с точки зрения производительности, лучше собирать строку всего добавляемого куска разметки, потом один раз делать append.  
Теория хороша, но надо уметь ее применять, в различных ситуациях могут быть полезны разные паттерны. Тут ничего полезного не скажу..

Comment: спасибо большое. начал пользоваться вариантом с $p=(div бла-бла), потом аппендить его, столкнулся с тем что не могу нормально вложить объекты друг в друга...в общем, я запоролся, но спасибо огромное, многое начал копать благодаря вам) как вопрос закрыть, кстати? а то это мой первый вопрос...

Comment: Пробуйте, делайте как вам удобно. Стопроцентно правильного метода нету.  
ЗЫ Закрывать вопрос не обязательно.

Answer (score 3):

Можно:

1. ручками разложить по дивам (через [JQuery.html(...)](http://api.jquery.com/html/), например);
2. воспользоваться одним из MV*-фреймворков, которые умеют связывать данные и представления (например, [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/));
3. написать свой Model-View binding (см. пункт 1).

Comment: Backbone.js пока что не могу использовать, из-за тяжелой корпоративной политики в плане кода (тимлид не воспринимает новые варианты, вот такой вот у нас тимлид))), но вы меня поняли, спасибо))) а как примерно выглядит конструкция которая раскладывает model по view? Примерно как for(child in parent), обходить циклом и там пихать их по дивам, или я неправильно понял?

Comment: ну и плюс сроки - совсем уже вчера, я просто не успею, ибо в веб-разработке не так давно, поэтому на эту библиотеку время есть только в перспективе, но не прямо сейчас, к сожалению(

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно о чём вы. Если вы получаете строку {'day':30,'month':2,'year':2013} как json, то пускаете эту строку под

```
var data = JSON.parse("{'day':30,'month':2,'year':2013}");
```

И получаете например day вот так:

```
var day = data.day.getNumber();
```

Ну а этот day пихаете:

```
document.getElementById('dayblock').innerHTML = day;
```

[p.](http://learn.javascript.ru/json)[s.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: нет, не совсем то - строку я уже получил, уже распарсил ее через $.ajax, указав dataType: json. проблема не в том, что я не могу перевести строку json в JS'объект, а в том, что не понимаю, как в эти объекты добавить отображение

Comment: Покажите что вы уже написали (от подгрузки до парсинга)

Comment: а как тут код пихать нормально? pastebin'ом?...
вот - http://pastebin.com/w4icWVdn - это был ajax и клиентский javaScript (там уже есть другие объекты-контейнеры, не обращайте на них внимания). там много черновиков, просто не успел отредактировать. Создается units=new Array(), вот там и начинается. по нажатию кнопки #show вылетает дата на сервак.
Вот серверный скрипт - http://pastebin.com/0aeSqMgu.
В итоге происходит примерно следующее - выборка из базы парсится, на выходе получается многомерный массив, причем группы могут находится как на первом уровне массива, так и на других

Comment: там в этом javaScript-файле чуть выше чем объявление массива units есть другие объекты, а именно periods, и там как раз соблюдается подвложенность, и вызов всех процедур для отображения тоже есть. Но вопрос как раз в том, как не писать функции наподобие importPeriod(), а просто передав через JSON, распарсить полученные объекты уже на клиенте, не вызывая (но это необязательно) конструкторы объекта? Если что непонятно в коде, спрашивайте, все скажу) ну и не судите строго, если там все криво

Comment: простите, переносы строки в комментариях почему-то не отображаются(

Comment: Код ещё кстати норм. Строка 99. Насколько я понял вы тут получили data и застряли. Тоже самое на 314. Парсера т.е. нет? Если я прав, то кидайте data в JSON.parse() и ловите объект:

var dataobj = JSON.parse(data);